# string substitution not working for html insert

Tags: python, html

The script receives two variables from a previous web page. From those variables, the code determines which images are desired. It sends those images to a temp folder, zips up that folder and places it in an output folder for pickup. That's where things go south. I'm trying to allow the webpage to provide a button for the user to click on and download the zip file. Because the zip file's name needs to change based on the variables the script receives, I cannot just make a generic link to the zip file.

```
import arcpy, sys, shutil, os
path = "C:/output/exportedData/raw/"
pathZip = "C:/output/exportedData/zip/"

#First arg is the mxd base filename which is the same as the geodatabase name
geodatabaseName = "C:/output/" + sys.argv[1] + ".gdb"

#this is where the images are determined and sent to a folder

zipFileName = sys.argv[1]
zipFile = shutil.make_archive(path + zipFileName,"zip")
movedZip = os.rename(zipFile, pathZip + zipFileName + ".zip")
shutil.rmtree(path + zipFileName)
print """<h3><a href="{}">Download zip file</a></h3>""".format(movedZip)
```

And the last line indicates where the problem comes in.  Firebug indicates the link made is

```
<a href="None">Download zip file</a>
```

The string substitution isn't working in this case and I'm at a loss as to why.  Thank you, in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`os.rename()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename) doesn't return anything, which means that `movedZip` becomes `None`.

Here's what you probably want to do instead:

```
movedZip = pathZip + zipFileName + ".zip"
os.rename(zipFile, movedZip)
```

Comment: Ah, very nice.  That worked.  Thank you.  However, now when I click the link, it doesn't respond.  When I hover over the link, the address displayed is "file:///C:output/exportedData/zip/zippedfile.zip".  Do I need to trim the input variable in some way?

Comment: @Iakona what is your desired link text?

Answer (score 0):

The os.rename method does not return any value. You could see the official document [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename). It rename the file or directory src to dst. Some exceptions might be thrown. But does not return anything.